# Calculate time duration value from 2 select time options in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that has select values TIME FROM: and TIME TO:.

They are in the format TIME FROM:, select time hour, then select am or pm

The select TIME TO: is in the format , select time hour, then select am or pm

How could I get the duration between the selected values and have the duration input field filled

Example

1) 1:00 pm  - 5:00 pm = 4 hours duration / duration input filled with 4 hours

2) 9:00 am  - 3:30 pm = 6.5 hours duration / duration input filled with 6.5 hours

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-2"></div>
<div class="col-lg-10">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-2 text-semibold">From:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="time_from" name="time_from" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">1:00</option>
                        <option value="130">1:30</option>
                        <option value="2">2:00</option>
                        <option value="230">2:30</option>
                        <option value="3">3:00</option>
                        <option value="330">3:30</option>
                        <option value="4">4:00</option>
                        <option value="430">4:30</option>
                        <option value="5">5:00</option>
                        <option value="530">5:30</option>
                        <option value="6">6:00</option>
                        <option value="630">6:30</option>
                        <option value="7">7:00</option>
                        <option value="730">7:30</option>
                        <option value="8">8:00</option>
                        <option value="830">8:30</option>
                        <option value="9">9:00</option>
                        <option value="930">9:30</option>
                        <option value="10">10:00</option>
                        <option value="1030">10:30</option>
                        <option value="11">11:00</option>
                        <option value="1130">11:30</option>
                        <option value="12">12:00</option>
                        <option value="1230">12:30</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="time_from_am_pm" name="time_from_am_pm" class="form-control">
                        <option value="pm">pm</option>
                        <option value="am">am</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-2 pl-20 text-semibold">To:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="time_to" name="time_to" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">1:00</option>
                        <option value="130">1:30</option>
                        <option value="2">2:00</option>
                        <option value="230">2:30</option>
                        <option value="3">3:00</option>
                        <option value="330">3:30</option>
                        <option value="4">4:00</option>
                        <option value="430">4:30</option>
                        <option value="5">5:00</option>
                        <option value="530">5:30</option>
                        <option value="6">6:00</option>
                        <option value="630">6:30</option>
                        <option value="7">7:00</option>
                        <option value="730">7:30</option>
                        <option value="8">8:00</option>
                        <option value="830">8:30</option>
                        <option value="9">9:00</option>
                        <option value="930">9:30</option>
                        <option value="10">10:00</option>
                        <option value="1030">10:30</option>
                        <option value="11">11:00</option>
                        <option value="1130">11:30</option>
                        <option value="12">12:00</option>
                        <option value="1230">12:30</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="time_to_am_pm" name="time_to_am_pm" class="form-control">
                        <option value="pm">pm</option>
                        <option value="am">am</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-lg-2 text-semibold">Duration:</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" name="booking_duration" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like its homework. Convert times to seconds and Subtract them

Comment: its for a booking form I am creating for  a website, I no its not that complex, just hoping someone with better experience in jquery/javascript then me can provide the best solution for this

Comment: Try [moment js](http://momentjs.com/) it might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using momentjs you can write a change event handler for the four fields:

```
$('#time_from, #time_from_am_pm, #time_to, #time_to_am_pm').on('change', function(e) {
  var timeFrom = moment($('#time_from option:selected').text() + 
              $('#time_from_am_pm option:selected').text(), 'HH:mma');
 var timeTo = moment($('#time_to option:selected').text() + 
              $('#time_to_am_pm option:selected').text(), 'HH:mma');
 var dif = timeTo.diff(timeFrom);
 if (dif < 0) {
    timeTo = timeTo.add(1, 'days');
    dif = timeTo.diff(timeFrom);
 }
 var d = moment.duration(dif);
 var result = +d.get('hours') + (+d.get('minutes') / 60);
 $('[name="booking_duration"]').val(result);
```

});

The snippet:

```js
$('#time_from, #time_from_am_pm, #time_to, #time_to_am_pm').on('change', function(e) {
  var timeFrom = moment($('#time_from option:selected').text() + $('#time_from_am_pm option:selected').text(), 'HH:mma');
  var timeTo = moment($('#time_to option:selected').text() + $('#time_to_am_pm option:selected').text(), 'HH:mma');
  var dif = timeTo.diff(timeFrom);
  if (dif < 0) {
    timeTo = timeTo.add(1, 'days');
    dif = timeTo.diff(timeFrom);
  }
  var d = moment.duration(dif);
  var result = +d.get('hours') + (+d.get('minutes') / 60);
  $('[name="booking_duration"]').val(result);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-10">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2 text-semibold">From:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select id="time_from" name="time_from" class="form-control">
              <option value="1">1:00</option>
              <option value="130">1:30</option>
              <option value="2">2:00</option>
              <option value="230">2:30</option>
              <option value="3">3:00</option>
              <option value="330">3:30</option>
              <option value="4">4:00</option>
              <option value="430">4:30</option>
              <option value="5">5:00</option>
              <option value="530">5:30</option>
              <option value="6">6:00</option>
              <option value="630">6:30</option>
              <option value="7">7:00</option>
              <option value="730">7:30</option>
              <option value="8">8:00</option>
              <option value="830">8:30</option>
              <option value="9">9:00</option>
              <option value="930">9:30</option>
              <option value="10">10:00</option>
              <option value="1030">10:30</option>
              <option value="11">11:00</option>
              <option value="1130">11:30</option>
              <option value="12">12:00</option>
              <option value="1230">12:30</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select id="time_from_am_pm" name="time_from_am_pm" class="form-control">
              <option value="pm">pm</option>
              <option value="am">am</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2 pl-20 text-semibold">To:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select id="time_to" name="time_to" class="form-control">
              <option value="1">1:00</option>
              <option value="130">1:30</option>
              <option value="2">2:00</option>
              <option value="230">2:30</option>
              <option value="3">3:00</option>
              <option value="330">3:30</option>
              <option value="4">4:00</option>
              <option value="430">4:30</option>
              <option value="5">5:00</option>
              <option value="530">5:30</option>
              <option value="6">6:00</option>
              <option value="630">6:30</option>
              <option value="7">7:00</option>
              <option value="730">7:30</option>
              <option value="8">8:00</option>
              <option value="830">8:30</option>
              <option value="9">9:00</option>
              <option value="930">9:30</option>
              <option value="10">10:00</option>
              <option value="1030">10:30</option>
              <option value="11">11:00</option>
              <option value="1130">11:30</option>
              <option value="12">12:00</option>
              <option value="1230">12:30</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-5 pr-20">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select id="time_to_am_pm" name="time_to_am_pm" class="form-control">
              <option value="pm">pm</option>
              <option value="am">am</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-lg-2 text-semibold">Duration:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" name="booking_duration" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is "mementjs" ?

Comment: @Jhecht Sorry. It's my typo.

Comment: just one very small problem , say someone selects 11pm to 3am, which would be 4 hours? we need to calculate forward instead of getting a minus value returned

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jquery-timepicker](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker) time pickers to get a valid date object with the time and use the following code to calculate duration

```
//this returns duration in hours
var calculateDuration = function(timefrom,timeto){
      var d = (timeto.getTime()-timefrom.getTime())/60000;
      return d<0?0:d;
}
```

Comment: A result of -6 is still a significant result. Maybe you should use `return Math.abs(d);`?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel  yes you could use `Math.abs(d)` if you don't care about chronological order order of `timeFrom` and `timeTo`